# Pass Dynamically columns,table name as parameters in stored procedure and update columns that are passed in parameters

Tags: oracle

i want to update only that columns which are passed in parameters in stored procedure using Oracle.also the table name is passed as a parameter.i have tried some code but was not able to update only the columns that are passed in parameters. 
Here is the code:

```
create or replace procedure update_procedure (e_id IN emp_details.emp_id%TYPE,e_nm IN emp_details.emp_name%TYPE)
IS
old_val varchar2(3000);
stmt varchar2(3000);
begin
     select emp_name into old_val from emp_details where emp_id=e_id;
     update emp_details set emp_name=e_nm where emp_id=e_id;
     stmt := 'insert into temp values (1,'|| old_val ||','||e_nm||')'; 
     commit; 
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have emp_details, and what was your error ? to know that run this in plsql `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE NAME ='UPDATE_PROCEDURE''`

in the mean time , this procedure is working I replaced `emp_details` with emp_category

```
create or replace procedure update_procedure (E_ID IN emp_category.comp_code%TYPE,e_nm IN emp_category.BRIEF_DESC_ENG%TYPE)
IS
old_val varchar2(3000);
stmt varchar2(3000);
begin
     select BRIEF_DESC_ENG into old_val from emp_category where COMP_CODE=E_ID;
     update emp_category set BRIEF_DESC_ENG=e_nm where COMP_CODE=E_ID;
     --stmt := 'insert into temp values (1,'|| old_val ||','||e_nm||')';
     commit;
end;
```

example how to pass a parameter :

```
create table ex_employee (f_name varchar2(100), id number(2))
/
create or replace procedure update_procedure (name varchar2, e_id number)
IS
begin
     update ex_employee set F_NAME=name where ID=E_ID;
     commit; 
end;
/
```

in the above example i created a test table , then a procedure that pass id and name. try it

Comment: thanks for ur reply.My question is i am passing emp_name statically..i want to pass columns dynamically for e.g:
update table_name set column_name=value where id=value
here the table_name,column_name and value all three should be passed as a parameter in the stored procedure.
update only that columns of the table which are passed in the parameters of the stored procedure

Comment: I did that in the procedure , you pass a value id for comp code and value for breif_desc_eng , those variables will be updated in the table emp_category